# bindActionCreators not getting to dispatch on array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-props

I am trying to call actions on an array ob objects.The action is called on the onSuccess method of a previous action. When calling the action on a single object I am able to execute everything properly but it never executes when I call them in a forEach or a for Loop.

this is my import

```js
import {createClient} from "../../store/actions/clients/clients.actions";
import {createNewContact} from "../../store/actions/contact-list/contact-list.actions";
```

this is my connect decorator

```js
@connect(
  state => ({avatarURL: state.avatar.URL}),
  dispatch => bindActionCreators({modalVisibility, updateAvatarURL, createClient, createNewContact}, dispatch)
)
```

this is my two actions getting called

```js
    this.props.createClient({
      newClientData, onSuccess: (newClientData) => {
        for (let contact of values.contacts) {
          contact.clientId = newClientData.id;
          this.props.createNewContact(contact);
        }
        this.props.modalVisibility(false);
      }
    });
```

this is my action

```js
export const createNewContact = (params) => {
  debugger
  return dispatch => {
    let user = {
      email: params.email,
      name: params.firstName,
      surname: params.lastName,
      password: params.password,
      clientId: params.clientId
    };

    let onSuccess = () => {
      dispatch({
        type: actions.CREATE_CLIENT_SUCCESS,
        payload: {...params.newClientData}
      });

      if (params.onSuccess) params.onSuccess({...params.newClientData});
    };

    let onFailure = () => {
      dispatch({
        type: actions.CREATE_CLIENT_FAILURE,
        payload: error
      });

      if (params.onFailure) params.onFailure(error);
    };


    awsServices.createUserInTheGroup({...user, group: config.groups.clients}, onSuccess, onFailure);

  };
};
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe values.contacts is empty?

Comment: I could actually call it on the first child of the array succesfully with this.props.createNewContact(values.contact[0). it triggered succesfully.